# list.foreach vs foreach

Tags: c#, .net, linq, desempenho, característica-linguagem

Tenho uma lista com várias `string`, existe diferença entre percorrer os valores da lista:

Desta maneira:

```
ListaString.ForEach(delegate(string str)
{
    Console.WriteLine(str);
});
```

Ou desta:

```
foreach(string str in ListaString)
{
    Console.WriteLine(str);    
}
```

Um é mais performático que o outro? Existe algum ganho significativo?

Quando é recomendado usar `list.foreach`? e `foreach`? se tratando de `List<T>`.

OBS: Sei que o `Foreach` pode ser usado para percorrer `arrays` e outras coisas.
  Mas quero saber especificamente dessas duas maneiras colocadas acima em situações que envolvam `List<T>`.

Comment: Por ser um método de extensão (System.Linq) acredito que internamente ele deva chamar o foreach comum ou algo parecido, logo, a performance deve ser muito parecida. Quanto a utilização, acredito que vá de gosto. Se for algo simples, uma simples chamada ou uma concatenação, acredito que o list.ForEach fique mais bonito e simples de ler.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tem diferença, claro. A primeira pode ser mais lenta ([há controvérsias](https://stackoverflow.com/a/226029/221800) com meu [teste idêntico](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gV7mc9)) e é mais confusa. Tanto é confusa que nas implementações mais novas da classe (como na API WinRT, por exemplo) ela foi até retirada já que não trazia benefícios e era abusada.

- a semântica é diferente
- a maneira como as variáveis enclausuradas são tratadas é diferente
- é esquisito de ler
- ela não permite certas construções, como a do `continue` e `break`
- é difícil depurar.

A primeira é considerada estilo mais funcional, mas [há quem discorde](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21008099/221800).

Em geral as pessoas não entendem as peculiaridades de se executar o laço dentro do método em vez do código que está sendo escrito ali. Melhor fazer o que você entende melhor. Se não vai te trazer vantagens e se aumenta as chances de fazer algo errado sem querer, não use.

E olha que eu estou falando de usar com *lambda* e não com `delegate` que torna o código até maior.

O [Eric Lippert escreveu sobre isto](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/foreach-vs-foreach?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Note que isto é diferente do [`ForEachParallel`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/foreach-vs-foreach?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) que tem vantagens por fazer paralelismo, onde ele pode ser alcançado e traz vantagens claras em certos cenários.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: +1 por mencionar o `ForEachParallel`, um ponto curioso sobre o foreach, é que quando tento chamar o `SaveChanges()` do EF dentro do foreach, ele dispara uma excessão informando que não pode abrir uma transação, pois já existe uma em outra thread, este comportamento não ocorre se o mesmo código for reescrito usando um for convencional, nunca entendi o por que.

Comment: @TobyMosque não sei porque também, mas tem a ver com essas diferenças semânticas.

Answer (score 4):

Seguinte, em termos de desempenho não existe uma diferença significativa, você pode até ver isto no seguinte fiddle:

[https://dotnetfiddle.net](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cmV7Ub)

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{   
    public static void Main()
    {       
        var lista = Enumerable.Range(0, 50000).Select(indice => Guid.NewGuid()).ToList();
        
        var relogio = new Stopwatch();
        relogio.Start();
        
        for (var indice = 0; indice < lista.Count; indice++)
        {
            //var reverse = Enumerable.Reverse(lista[indice].ToByteArray());
        }
        Console.WriteLine(relogio.Elapsed);
        
        relogio.Restart();      
        foreach (var item in lista)
        {
            //var reverse = Enumerable.Reverse(item.ToByteArray());
        }
        Console.WriteLine(relogio.Elapsed);
        
        relogio.Restart();      
        lista.ForEach((item) => {
            //var reverse = Enumerable.Reverse(item.ToByteArray());
        });
        Console.WriteLine(relogio.Elapsed);
    }
}
```

Outro ponto que gostaria de mencionar, é que o Linq não implementa um método extensivo ForEach para a Interface IEnumerable, apenas temos o método nativo do List.

Tambem gostaria de apontar à justificativa dada pelo Eric Lippert no [Link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/foreach-vs-foreach):

`foos.ForEach((Foo foo)=>{ statement involving foo; });` é dificil de ler e debugar, alem de pode introduzir outros problemas.