# O que caracteriza a programação imperativa e funcional?

Tags: javascript, terminologia, programação-funcional, programação-imperativa

O que caracteriza a programação imperativa e funcional e quais são as diferenças entre elas em relação uma com a outra?

Não consigo compreender esses dois paradigmas.

Nota:

> Se puder citar exemplos delas, de preferência em JavaScript.

Comment: Relacionado: ["Programação Funcional e Programação Orientada a Objetos. O que são e quais suas principais diferenças?"](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13372/215) Não é exatamente uma duplicata (pois aqui se pede "imperativa" e lá "orientada a objeto"), mas a resposta lá aborda esse paradigma.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[O **paradigma imperativo** é aquele que expressa o código através de comandos ao computador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141624/101). Uma outra característica marcante é a mutação de estado (alterar os valores dos objetos). Funciona como uma receita de bolo.

Tem [mais informações sobre o imperativo em outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81854/101).

O **paradigma funcional** costuma expressar o código principalmente através de funções e evita a mutação de estado. Você diz como deseja o bolo e ele será feito, portanto tende ser mais expressivo.

## JavaScript

Aproveitando a [pergunta anterior do AP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/126886/101), se eu tivesse que escolher só um paradigma para o JS, seria o imperativo. Na verdade este é o paradigma principal de todas as principais linguagens do mercado. O tempo todo as pessoas estão mudando estado dos objetos disponíveis e ficam mandando o computador executar instruções. Em pontos específicos a expressão e organização do código pode ser feita de outra forma. É importante dizer que o JS tem alguns poucos elementos que caracterizam o paradigma funcional (isso foi aumentando com o tempo).

Quando estamos controlando fluxo no código (`if`, `switch`, `while`, `for`, `throw` e até mesmo chamadas de funções simples) estamos programando imperativamente.

Quando preferimos usar uma função recursiva para repetir execução em vez de um `for` ou `while` estamos aplicando um estilo mais funcional.

De fato as linguagens funcionais puras só podem expressar repetição desta forma. Assim como as decisões são tomadas através de [*pattern matching*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern_matching) que é parecido com o `switch`, mas bem mais sofisticado permitindo o uso de várias formas, e sempre resulta em alguma coisa, ao contrário do `switch` que determina o que executar.

## Confusão entre paradigmas

É um engano chamar uma linguagem de funcional só porque ela tem função. Essencialmente todas linguagens possuem funções. A forma como ele é usada, entre outras características, é que vai determinar se ela é funcional. E me causa arrepios quando a pessoa acha que linguagem funcional é aquela que tem funções, e procedural é a que tem procedimentos. Toda linguagem imperativa que eu conheço é procedural, mesmo aquelas que usam funções. A função no paradigma funcional é expressada num sentido mais matemático.

## JS *pode* ser funcional

JavaScript possui [funções de primeira classe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function) ([função anônima](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function), [*closure*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29)). Ou seja, as funções podem ser tratadas como dados, e por isso podem ser armazenadas em variáveis, passadas como argumentos para outra funções. As funções podem ser recursivas. A linguagem pára aí no paradigma funcional. O resto que caracteriza uma linguagem funcional só pode ser aplicado de forma indireta e por convenção, isto inclui [funções puras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purely_functional) (sem [efeitos colaterais](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_%28computer_science%29)), [funções de alta ordem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function), [avaliação preguiçosa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation) ou [parcial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_evaluation), [transparência referencial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency), etc.

Algumas bibliotecas e *frameworks*, como o jQuery por exemplo, adotam uma postara de programação funcional. Quando você usa uma função `forEach()` ao invés de um `for` está adotando o estilo mais funcional, ainda que internamente a execução da função seja toda imperativa.

Então você pode adotar o estilo funcional, mas nunca programará de forma totalmente funcional em JS.

## Qual usar?

Como a maioria das pessoas tem dificuldades de abstrações e conceitos matemáticos, normalmente é mais fácil entender os códigos de forma imperativa, que é mais próximo do que concretamente é executado pelo computador. Não é por acaso que seja mais fácil criar linguagens imperativas.

Claro que se o programador apenas tiver que consumir elementos funcionais prontos fica fácil usar. Assim como OOP, consumir é fácil, criar estruturas para serem consumidas da forma correta não é tão fácil assim.

Assim como OOP, o paradigma funcional é uma forma de abstrair algumas coisas, expressar melhor a intenção, **o que se deseja fazer**, e menos o **como se deve fazer**.

Outro motivo das pessoas preferirem o imperativo<sup>*</sup> é que por estar mais próximo do que o computador vai executar é mais fácil conseguir a melhor performance, ou pelo menos prever o tempo mais facilmente (pra tudo tem exceções).

Forçar o estilo mais funcional sem saber bem o que está fazendo não parece ser uma boa ideia, principalmente quando se está fazendo por modismo. Se é para adotar um paradigma, é porque está muito acostumado com ele e ele vai resolver um problema de forma melhor.

Há vários pequenos problemas em JS que são resolvidos assim e costuma-se ter este estilo em bibliotecas, exemplos, ou mesmo na API padrão dos navegadores ou outros hospedeiros.

Pode dar a impressão do paradigma funcional ser mais fácil, afinal basta dizer o que quer e magicamente tudo é executado sem se preocupar com os detalhes. Isso é ótimo, até que precisa algo um pouco diferente, até que as coisas não aconteçam exatamente como esperava em todas situações.

## Exemplos

#### Imperativo

```
function join(array) {
    var text = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        text += array[i];
    }
    return text;
}
```

#### Funcional (ECMAScript 5)

```
function join(array, i, text) {
    var i = typeof(i) !== "undefined" ?  i : 0;
    var text = typeof(text) !== "undefined" ?  text : "";
    return (i == array.length) ? text : join(array, i + 1, text + array[i]);
}
```

#### Funcional (ECMAScript 6)

```
function join([ head = '', ...tail ], text = '') {
    return tail.length === 0 ? (text + head) : join(tail, text + head);
}
```

#### forEach()

```
Array.prototype.forEach = function(callback) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        callback(this[i], i, this);
    }
}
```

Aí pode usá-la no lugar de fazer o laço na mão. Isto pode ser considerado um abuso, principalmente se não trouxer uma vantagem clara. Há diversas [desvantagens](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/78470/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Syntax/ImperativeXFunctional.js).

## Conclusão

Você tem que escolher entre ter total controle do que está fazendo e ter melhores abstrações do que deve fazer.

Se quiser conhecer uma linguagem mais funcional, sugiro [OCaml](https://ocaml.org/). Ela tem todos os conceitos funcionais, mas não fica tão distante de outras linguagens.

Perguntas relacionadas:

- [Como funcionam Closures em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1859/101)
- [Como funcionam funções anônimas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/9936/101)
- [Qual a diferença entre uma expressão lambda, um closure e um delegate?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34907/101)
- [Programação Funcional e Programação Orientada a Objetos. O que são e quais suas principais diferenças?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13372/101)
- [O que é callback?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27177/101)

<sup>*</sup>Pode parecer que orientação a objeto é o paradigma preferido. Se perguntar para as pessoas a maioria seguirá a moda e dizer que prefere ele, mas programam imperativamente a maior parte do tempo. E é pior, é tão grave o desconhecimento que muitos falam que fazem OOP e os seus códigos são 100% imperativos, porque é isso que ela saber fazer, mas não quer estar de fora da moda, por isso diz que faz.

Comment: acho que sua resposta tem muitos links... mas foi uma boa resposta :)

Comment: Aí fica seu critério clicar neles ou não. Se não tivesse, aí não teria a opção. Internet sem *links* não é internet :) Obrigado.

Comment: Uma pegada funcional com ES6:
https://jsfiddle.net/h6z3xgqr/1

Comment: @GabrielKatakura Legal, pode por na resposta?

Answer (score 16):

## Paradigma Imperativo

Na programação imperativa você toma o controle total do que está sendo executado no programa e dita através de comandos, passo a passo, o que deve ser feito.

Nesse paradigma, geralmente você trabalha alterando diretamente o estado dos objetos ou estruturas de dados que fazem parte do algoritmo

No exemplo abaixo, fiz um algoritmo bem simples que seleciona todos os produtos de uma lista que são mais baratos do que 3 Reais:

```
function selecionarTudoAbaixoDeTresReaisImperativo(produtos) {
  var produtosSelecionados = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < produtos.length; i++) {
    if (produtos[i].preco < 3.00) {
      produtosSelecionados.push(produtos[i].nome);
    }
  }
  return produtosSelecionados;
}
```

Note que o algoritmo seque uma sequência de passos que itera sobre a lista de produtos e vai condicionalmente adicionando os itens na lista de produtos selecionados.

## Paradigma funcional

Na programação funcional a ideia é fazer o que você quer com base na execução de operações - ou funções - nos objetos.

Nesse paradigma geralmente não se altera o estado dos objetos, mas cada função executada num objeto retorna um novo objeto com o resultado da operação realizada.

O mesmo exemplo anterior no paradigma funcional:

```
function selecionarTudoAbaixoDeTresReaisFuncional(produtos) {
  var itemMenorQueTres = function(item) { return item.preco < 3.00; };
  var pegarSomenteNome = function(item) { return item.nome };
  return produtos.filter(itemMenorQueTres).map(pegarSomenteNome);
}
```

Note que em nenhum momento alteramos algum objeto explicitamente. No entanto, executamos duas operações funcionais na lista `produtos`:

1. Filtramos os itens com `filter` de acordo com o critério implementado na função `itemMenorQueTres`. Isso gera uma nova lista.
2. Mapeamos os objetos filtrados e retornados após o `filter` usando a função `map`, que transforma a lista de produtos numa lista com os nomes dos produtos. Na verdade "transformar" significa criar uma nova lista num novo formato.

## Resultados

Os dois trechos de código são equivalentes do ponto de vista computacional, no sentido de que para cada entrada, eles produzem a mesma saída.

Podemos testá-los da seguinte forma:

```
var frutas = [
    { nome: "Laranja", preco: 3.99 },
    { nome: "Melancia", preco: 2.99 },
    { nome: "Banana", preco: 1.99 }
];
console.log(selecionarTudoAbaixoDeTresReaisImperativo(frutas));
console.log(selecionarTudoAbaixoDeTresReaisFuncional(frutas));
```

Ambos imprimirão a lista `["Melancia", "Banana"]` no console.

#### [Veja o código funcionando aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/utluiz/2gpgnyyd/).

## Considerações

A programação imperativa provê mais controle e é mais próxima da linguagem de máquina, final a máquina só entende comandos diretos. O desempenho de linguagens paradigmas geralmente é melhor, para o mesmo tipo de linguagem, porque ele pode ser mais facilmente traduzido para algo mais perto da linguagem de máquina.

Entretanto, ter o controle total também significa cometer mais erros ou estar mais propenso a fazer isto sem perceber. O fato das linguagens imperativas frequentemente darem preferência a trabalhar com objetos mutáveis é uma grande barreira para processamento *multithreading*.

A programação funcional tenta resolver vários desses problemas e tendem a gerar um programa mais modular, que funciona nativamente com paralelismo, algumas vezes mais fácil de ler, além de incorrer em menos erros grosseiros como laços infinitos e semelhantes, já que você não executa o laço explicitamente. Por exemplo:

```
return produtos.filter(itemMenorQueTres).map(pegarSomenteNome);
```

Isso é muito mais fácil de entender do que a versão imperativa, com um porém.

A grande desvantagem da programação funcional é que ela pode ser de difícil entendimento para quem não está devidamente treinado nos conceitos.

Em outras palavras: ela não é tão natural para os humanos quanto a lista de comandos no paradigma imperativo.

## Qual é melhor?

É importante entender que não existe realmente um consenso sobre qual dos paradigmas é melhor.

Muitas pessoas afirmam que, assim como qualquer ferramenta, cada uma delas tem aplicações em áreas diferentes. Entretanto, defensores de cada paradigma sempre tem algum argumento para dizer que o seu paradigma predileto também pode resolver outros tipos de problema de forma pelo menos razoável.

Recentemente houve uma discussão envolvendo centenas de pessoas na empresa onde trabalho, devido a um *bug* muito difícil de descobrir num trecho de código puramente funcional. O ocorrido levantou uma bandeira vermelha para alguns sobre o problema da complexidade de algumas implementações funcionais.

Conclusão: temos que conhecer os dois paradigmas e usar aquele que pareça fazer mais sentido em cada caso. Se começar a cheirar mal, simplesmente troque.

Comment: Fiz uma pergunta a respeito do seu relato sobre esse bug, acredito que sua resposta lá pode ser de grande valia: [A Programação Funcional pode dificultar o descobrimento de certos tipos de bugs?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/402261/a-programa%c3%a7%c3%a3o-funcional-pode-dificultar-o-descobrimento-de-certos-tipos-de-bugs). Obrigado.