# Diferença entre algoritmos que leem números até receber o número 999

Tags: python, algoritmo, while, controle-de-fluxo

Qual a diferença destes códigos?

Primeiro código:

```
cont = 0 
n = 0 
total = 0 
n = int(input("Digite 999 para parar")) 
while n != 999: 
  n = int(input("Digite 999 para parar"))
  cont += 1 
  total += n 
print(total)
```

Segundo código:

```
cont = 0 
n = 0 
total = 0 
n = int(input("Digite 999 para parar")) 
while n != 999: 
  cont += 1 
  total += n 
  n = int(input("Digite 999 para parar")) 
  print(total)
```

Eu sei a solução, mas não compreendo o porquê a diferença sendo que no "PRIMEIRO" o `while` deveria ser interrompido em "n = int(input(digite 999 para... )" e não somar o 999 na variável total sendo que está no começo do `while`.

Comment: Já tentou fazer o teste de mesa?

Comment: Sim.  A minha duvida é se quando ele entra no loop while e a condição para sair é verdadeira, ele executa todos os comandos ou ele sai onde estiver no loop.

Comment: Tente fazer o equivalente em python desse pseudo-código: `i = 0; cond = true; while (cond) { cond = false; i = 1; } print(i);` ... qual o valor de `i` que será impresso?

Comment: É foi bem esclarecedor, mas decepcionante. Eu Jurava que o código era interrompido quando a condição fosse verdadeira. Obrigado ! Obs:  1

Comment: E é. O que acontece no primeiro código é que, ao informar o primeiro valor, caso você informe um valor diferente de 999, este valor será ignorado e será feita uma nova leitura. Além disso você também somará o 999.

Comment: i = 0
cond = True
while cond:
    i = 1
    cond = False
    i = 2
print(i)
a reposta é 2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nos comentários diz ter feito teste de mesa. Mas ou não entendeu o que é o teste de mesa, ou não entendeu como um código funciona, ambos produzirão resultados errados. Para dar certo precisa ter completo entendimento do que está fazendo.

Python é uma linguagem essencialmente do [paradigma](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141624/101) [imperativo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/127121/101) por isso ela executa ações através de mecanismos. Então cada passo a ser executado ocorrerá em cada vez. Eu poderia falar cada linha, mas nem é isso, mesmo em uma linha pode ter vários passos que serão executados de acordo com regras de precedência e associatividade. De maneira alguma algo é executado fora de ordem. O que o código imperativo pode fazer é mudar **explicitamente** para onde vai a seguir, se nada for feito sempre será o próximo passo dentro das regras citadas acima ou na próxima linha.

Não existe um mecanismo implícito que a cada mudança de estado do código algo será executado sem você perceber para tomar uma decisão ou fazer outra ação. Só porque `n` mudou de valor não quer dizer que a condição será avaliada novamente.

É possível fazer uma linguagem assim, mas não considera-se adequado para a imensa maioria dos casos. É possível até você criar uma abstração que faça isso ou criar um código que faça isso explicitamente. Geralmente não compensa e é melhor reformular o código, o que você fez, e é um bom exercício para entender como o código realmente funciona e como programar da forma mais adequada. Hoje a imensa maioria dos "programadores" não sabem programar, eles não entendem o que o código realmente faz e não conseguem reformar seus códigos.

Você poderia encerrar assim:

```
cont = 0
n = 0
total = 0
n = int(input("Digite 999 para parar"))
while n != 999:
    n = int(input("Digite 999 para parar"))
    if n == 999: break
    cont += 1
    total += n
print(total)
```

Mas não aconselho, seu segundo código é muito mais claro e simples, apesar de que a indentação introduziu um *bug* nele. O primeiro também parece ter um *bug*, ele pede um dado uma vez e ignora, depois pede de novo.

Na verdade seu código ainda tem um problema de repetição e pode ser simplificado:

```
cont = 0
n = 0
total = 0
while True:
    n = int(input("Digite 999 para parar"))
    if n == 999: break
    cont += 1
    total += n
print(total)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/2K6FNx). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/hyktbwkz-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/LoopExit.py).

Assim o código fica mais [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101) e faz tudo como deve ser saindo no momento que deseja. Obviamente ainda espero que faça algo com `cont` e `total`, se não usá-los nem deveria estar aí.

Comment: Estou aprendendo mesmo. É um exercício para iniciante.  Achei interessante como fez o loop. Eu nao fui ensinado dessa maneira, mas é muito mais agradável nesse exemplo. Muito obrigado pelo comentário !