# A Programação Funcional pode dificultar o descobrimento de certos tipos de bugs?

Tags: programação-funcional

Pelo que entendo, a programação funcional (ou pelo menos um estilo funcional de programação) facilita encontrar e evitar bugs (é fácil testar funções puras, a imutabilidade protege dados, coisas indeterminísticas como I/O são isoladas, etc.); mas lendo [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/127133/68989) me deparei com o seguinte relato:

> Recentemente houve uma discussão envolvendo centenas de pessoas na empresa onde trabalho, devido a um bug muito difícil de descobrir num trecho de código puramente funcional. O ocorrido levantou uma bandeira vermelha para alguns sobre o problema da complexidade de algumas implementações funcionais.

Então, há certos tipos de bugs que ficam encobertos mais facilmente em código funcional do que em códigos de outros paradigmas? E quais tipos de bugs seriam esses?

Comment: Certamente há, provavelmente todos relacionados ao fato de ter que usar alguns truques para fazer o que é simples em um paradigma mais imperativo, truques enganam o compilador e podem enganar o programador.

Comment: @Maniero a [resposta aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/402451/68989) do utluiz ilustra o seu pensamento? Ou, você estava pensando em outros tipos de problemas com a PF (problemas que podem facilitar/ocultar bugs) e que ainda não foram abordados?

Comment: Não exatamente porque ele falou dos problemas de usar funcional em uma linguagem não funcional, o que faz todo sentido, mas tem os problemas relacionados à programação funcional pura. Está bem respondido para sua dúvida em relação ao que ele falou lá na resposta original, se é isso que queria saber, ótimo, se queria saber de forma geral o que pode ser complicado fazer no funcional eu acho que não é bem a mesma coisa. EU não me arrisco responder porque meu conhecimento de funcional ainda é, e acho que sempre será superficial, eu gosto, mas não uso fort emente. Faço alguma coisa funcional em C#.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### TL;DR

O caso em questão naquela postagem envolvia uma base de código funcional relativamente complexa, escrita em Java, e a questão da *accessibilidade* de um desenvolvedor, que não era familiar com ela, de forma que pudesse entender o que estava errado.

### Contraste de um código

Um trecho em particular era parecido com o seguinte:

```
Either<Exception, Iterable<QuoteResponse>> quoteRequestProcessed =
    sequenceRight(
        from(request.getQuoteRequests())
            .transform(
                curried(priceCalculator).apply(request)
            ));

if (quoteRequestProcessed.isLeft()) {
    return left(quoteRequestProcessed.left().get());
}
```

Um código imperativo equivalente seria:

```
List<QuoteResponse> responses = new ArrayList<>();
for (QuoteRequest quoteRequest : request.getQuoteRequests()) {
    responses.add(priceCalculator.apply(quoteRequest));
}
```

`priceCalculator` é uma função (`Function`) recebida.

Agora, pare e pense em casos excepcionais que podem ocorrer nos dois trechos. Por exemplo, o que aconteceria se `priceCalculator` lançasse uma exceção?

Bem, no segundo caso, a exceção seria lançada normalmente e você teria que capturá-la.

E no primeiro caso, que usa a abordagem funcional? A verdade é que não é possível dizer o resultado a não ser que você entenda conceitos como *currying*, *fluent iterables*, a convenção de *left* e *right* de um `Either` implementadas em uma biblioteca específica usada ali.

Eu não vou explicar o código functional de propósito, para você sentir um pouco mais a "dor" de quem estava depurando aquilo para encontrar o problema.

### Isolamento, tribalismo e elitismo

O resumo do caso é: **a sobrecarga causada pela quantidade de conceitos necessários para entender bem um código funcional pode impedir que um desenvolvedor "comum" compreenda completamente os cenários possíveis de execução daquele código**.

Claro que um desenvolvedor treinado naquela base de código poderia mais facilmente ter uma boa compreensão. No entanto, a realidade é que a curva de aprendizado impacta diretamente num ambiente dinâmico de uma empresa, onde projetos e pessoas vão e vêm.

Algo que adiciona ao problema é o "tribalismo" em equipes que adotam programação funcional, isto é, poucas pessoas constroem um jeito bem específico de desenvolvedor o sistema que torna contribuições externas quase impossíveis. Um jeito de fazer isto é criando um dialeto próprio, talvez uma biblioteca com funções que ninguém mais conhece. Não é incomum equipes que vivem isoladas das demais. Tais projetos tendem a surgir por um ou poucos entusiastas por PF e depois morrer tendem a morrer assim que eles deixam as empresas porque ninguém quer colocar a mão.

### Acessibilidade e portabilidade

Num ambiente colaborativo, a **portabilidade** de desenvolvedores faz toda a diferença. Embora eu defenda liberdade dos engenheiros em escolher a tecnologia mais adequada para resolver cada problema, é necessário também ter consciência de que você não é o dono do código.

Um jeito de contornar o problema de acessibilidade e portabilidade seria usar uma linguagem que seja naturalmente funcionais - e.g. Haskell, Erlang, Clojure, Scala - ou pelo menos padronizar o uso com bibliotecas já conhecidas.

Em minha opinião, a cultura da empresa vai ditar se é possível adotar uma linguagem funcional de mais alta complexidade ou se é melhor ater-se ao básico.

Comment: poxa vida, ainda não criaram a tal bala de prata.