# Uma consulta LINQ retorna qual tipo de dado?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, tipagem

Pesquisei a respeito do tipo de dado que é retornado quando executamos uma consulta em **LINQ**, porem não obtive sucesso.

Eu gostaria de saber que tipo de dado é retornado por uma consulta utilizando o **LINQ**, se é um objeto genérico ou um objeto do tipo da classe que representa a minha tabela no banco?

Vamos considerar este exemplo para ilustrar a situação:

```
var query = from p in database.Pessoa select p;
```

No exemplo acima, qual é o tipo de dado que seria assumido pela variável `query`?

Comment: Experimentaste compilar e ver qual o tipo inferido pelo compilador?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tem que ser um tipo [`IEnumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-8.0) (que não é um tipo concreto). Nada impede de retornar outros tipos que sejam adequados aos métodos normalmente usados no [LINQ](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/125601/101), desde que ele implemente o mesmo que um `IEnumerable` implementa. Ou seja, pode retornar qualquer tipo que implemente o método [`GetEnumerator()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1.getenumerator?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-8.0#System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_1_GetEnumerator). Porque o LINQ é apenas uma forma de pegar dados que podem ser enumerados.

Outra interface muito comum de ser usada no LINQ é a [`IQueryable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.iqueryable-1?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-8.0) que herda de `IEnumarable`, como pode ser visto na documentação. É o caso da expressão usada na pergunta. Qualquer coisa pode ser retornada, desde que seja `IEnumerable`.

## Como o LINQ funciona

O mais importante é que as pessoas imaginam que retorna um dado concreto, uma lista de dados que você pode ver na memória todos eles logo após executar esta expressão. Não é isso que ocorre de fato.

Se fizer um perfilamento ou algum acompanhamento de performance específico nessa expressão verá que ela é rápida demais. Mais ainda, ela tem complexidade essencialmente O(1). Não importando o tamanho dos dados que tem que manipular ela executa sempre no mesmo tempo (varia apenas de acordo com a complexidade da expressão, não dos dados). Geralmente fica na casa de poucos milissegundos, ou menos.

LINQ é uma tecnologia faz avaliação preguiçosa. Ele se vale dos geradores, são escritos com [`yield`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44293/101). Esse é o motivo de precisar de um `GetEnumerator()`, o `yield` é feito à base de uma enumeração.

De fato você só acessa os dados que realmente precisa na hora que for usar. Uma dessas formas é chamar um `ToList()`, `ToArray()` ou outro que exija dados concretos. Nesse momento a expressão realmente é aplicada à coleção original e gera uma outra coleção. Pode medir isso, costuma ser bem lento em casos de coleções grandes que precisam ser avaliadas. Por sorte algumas expressões não precisam ir até o fim para descobrir o que esperava.

Muitas vezes é um erro fazer isso. Muitos programadores fazem porque aprenderam que no final de uma expressão LINQ deve colocar esses métodos. Sim, em muitos casos deve mesmo, mas nem sempre. Quando isso é feito então é aplicado a expressão em todos os itens da coleção que precise avaliar e gera dados concretos. Há casos em que não deseja fazer essa consequência. Há casos que até deseja, mas pode fazer um laço junto com a avaliação dos itens. Quando se aplica um destes métodos que concretiza a coleção avaliada pelo LINQ e depois roda um laço, são dois laços ocorrendo, isso pode ser desperdício de recurso.

Alguns programadores acham o LINQ uma coisa mágica. Outros até pensam, "mas deve ser ineficiente fazer esse treco todo". Porque se tem um método que faz um laço em todos os itens, depois tem outro método que faz outro laço, e pode ter mais uma infinidade de métodos, cada um com um laço, deve ser bem lento executar tudo isso.

Se tiver curiosidade de ver [o fonte de um destes métodos](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,e2d8014ab698cbfc) ([no .NET Core](https://source.dot.net/#System.Linq/System/Linq/Where.cs,e2d8014ab698cbfc)) realmente tem um laço em cada. Mas o `yield` é o segredo. Na verdade ele só executa um passo do laço e encerra. Ou seja, ele aplica o predicado necessário no item e vai pro próximo método que aplica a sua parte e entrega para o próximo. Só depois de todos os métodos executarem em um item é que vai para o próximo item da coleção. Então na prática só um laço é executado não importa quantos métodos LINQ sejam invocados naquela expressão (isto pode ser um pouco mais complicado que isso em alguns casos, mas não vamos dificultar a explicação para ser mais preciso).

## Ineficiência

É claro que o `yield` tem seu custo. Se fizer na mão em um laço único juntando tudo o que precisa, certamente será mais rápido. Em alguns casos a perda de performance pode ser bem ruim. Em um banco de dados **pode** ser insignificante.

Tem gente que diz que a [perda de performance do LINQ é desprezível. Não é bem assim](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/78470/101). Tem casos que você sai de alguns microssegundos sem LINQ para milissegundos quando o usa. Pode ser milhares de vezes mais. E aí a pessoa diz que ainda será bem abaixo de um segundo. Mas se você colocar isso em um laço maior com milhares de execuções, é a diferença entre executar o todo em milissegundos ou em vários minutos.

## Conclusão

Então não ache que aquela variável (`query` no caso específico) tem algum dado nele logo em seguida. Ali tem um objeto com a expressão (de uma forma grossa o código necessário para executar a expressão) a ser executada, e não os dados.

Em um `IQueryable` ([veja a diferença](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17284/101)) provavelmente terá uma [forma de acessar uma expressão SQL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/125811/101) (não que precise) já montada durante a compilação da expressão em tempo de execução. O tempo aparentemente grande dessa expressão que não avalia dado algum é justamente por essa compilação.

Quando executa um método que concretiza a expressão o retorno será um tipo concreto que seja necessário. Nesse caso específico será uma [`List<Pessoa>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-8.0) (provavelmente, mas depende, pode ser [outra coleção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/76316/101)).]

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 7):

> No exemplo acima, qual é o tipo de dado que seria assumido pela variável `query`?

Um objeto que implementa [`IQueryable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb351562(v=vs.110).aspx), sendo `T` o tipo `Pessoa`.

`IQueryable` não é uma enumeração. É um objeto que constrói filtros que serão usados para compor uma enumeração em memória.

Considerando LINQ to Entities ou Entity Framework, a ideia aqui é construir um SQL baseado no predicado escrito e, ao resolver o objeto para uma enumeração (`IEnumerable`), o SQL é executado pelo provedor de dados e o retorno transformado em uma enumeração.

Caso fosse uma operação em memória, o LINQ construiria um objeto que funciona como filtro da enumeração, devolvendo outra enumeração com os resultados filtrados na resolução para `IEnumerable`.