# LINQ usando função dentro de select new{} com lambda expression

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, expressões-lambda

Estou montando um select, com o Entity Framework, que precisa "criar uma coluna" de acordo com 4 critérios. Estou tentando da seguinte maneira:

```
IQueryable<ImoveisDTO> Resultado = ctx.Imoveis.Select(ib => new ImoveisDTO
{
    idImovel = ib.idImovel,
    idStatusImovel = ib.idStatusImovel,
    idTipoImovel = ib.idTipoImovel,
    fltValorQuartosImovel = ib.fltValorQuartosImovel,
    FaixaPreco = MinhaFuncao(ib.fltValorQuartosImovel)
}
    ).Where(ib =>
    ib.NumerosQuartos.Contains(ib.intQuartos.Value)
    && FaixasPrecos.Contains(ib.FaixaPreco)
    ).Distinct()
```

Sendo MinhaFuncao:

```
private int MinhaFuncao(double? ValorQuarto)
{
    int FaixaRetornada;

    if (ValorQuarto < 150000) FaixaRetornada = 1;
    else if (ValorQuarto < 200000 && ValorQuarto > 150001) FaixaRetornada = 2;
    else if (ValorQuarto < 250000 && ValorQuarto > 200001) FaixaRetornada = 3;
    else if (ValorQuarto > 250001) FaixaRetornada = 4;
    else FaixaRetornada = 0;

    return FaixaRetornada;
}
```

Porém parece que não posso fazer isso pois estou recebendo a seguinte mensagem do LINQ:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 MinhaFuncao(System.Nullable`1[System.Double])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Já tentei colocar um If diretamente dentro do `Select new {FaixaPreco = if(ib. ...)}` Mas também não deu certo.

Qual a melhor maneira de resolver isso?

**-----Editado-------------------------**

Assim como o Manieiro sugeriu e o Marconcilio mostrou. Optei por usar o operador ternário que é traduzido como um CASE...WHEN.
Ficou assim:

```
IQueryable<ImoveisDTO> Resultado = ctx.Imoveis.Select(ib => new ImoveisDTO
{
    idImovel = ib.idImovel,
    idStatusImovel = ib.idStatusImovel,
    idTipoImovel = ib.idTipoImovel,
    fltValorQuartosImovel = ib.fltValorQuartosImovel,
    FaixaPreco = (ib.fltValorQuartosImovel < 150000 ? 1
                            : (ib.fltValorQuartosImovel < 200000 && ib.fltValorQuartosImovel > 150001) ? 2
                            : (ib.fltValorQuartosImovel < 250000 && ib.fltValorQuartosImovel > 200001) ? 3
                            : (ib.fltValorQuartosImovel > 250001) ? 4 : 0)
}
    ).Where(ib =>
    ib.NumerosQuartos.Contains(ib.intQuartos.Value)
    && FaixasPrecos.Contains(ib.FaixaPreco)
    ).Distinct()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

o EF não consegue interpretar métodos que não são rastreados por ele.

Uma forma de contornar isso é escrevendo sua função dentro da sua própria consulta.

```
IQueryable<ImoveisDTO> Resultado = ctx.Imoveis
.Select(ib => new ImoveisDTO
{
    idImovel = ib.idImovel,
    idStatusImovel = ib.idStatusImovel,
    idTipoImovel = ib.idTipoImovel,
    fltib.fltValorQuartosImovelsImovel = ib.fltib.fltValorQuartosImovelsImovel,
    FaixaPreco = (ib.fltValorQuartosImovel < 150000 ? 1
                        : (ib.fltValorQuartosImovel < 200000 && ib.fltValorQuartosImovel > 150001) ? 2
                        : (ib.fltValorQuartosImovel < 250000 && ib.fltValorQuartosImovel > 200001) ? 3
                        : (ib.fltValorQuartosImovel > 250001) ? 4 : 0),
})
.Where(ib => ib.NumerosQuartos.Contains(ib.intQuartos.Value) && FaixasPrecos.Contains(ib.FaixaPreco))
.Distinct()
```

A questão vai de seu uso se você só usar uma unica não vejo problema , mas se você tiver que ficar reutilizando o código em outras consultas talvez não seja uma das melhores soluções.

Comment: Hummm interessante. Eu tinha tentado com if() não com operador ternário.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro precisa [entender o LINQ](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/182176/101), por completo, antes de usar. [Veja mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/129810/101).

[Quando usa LINQ To Entities códigos C# precisam ser capazes de serem convertidos para SQL de forma eficiente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/125811/101). O melhor que pode acontecer é não funcionar. Muitas vezes funciona e o código gerado é muito ruim e a pessoa fica perdida.

[Um `IQueryable` é muito diferente de um `IEnumerable`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17284/101).

Então a solução é ter um código dentro do banco de dados que faça isto e possa ser invocado ou criar um [código que possa ser traduzido para o `CASE...WHEN`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/936136/221800).

[Usar `double` para valor monetário também é errado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Ou seja... tenho que criar uma view...

Comment: è uma possibilidade.